# Cone of influence in Morlet wavelet power spectra in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I am using Morlet wavelet for continuous wavelet analysis of my data in MATLAB. But the central frequency of the default wavelet  is 5 where as I wanted it 6. So I used a different method to built the desired wavelet using psi function i.e.

[psi,x]=cmorwavf(Lb,Ub,n5,fb,fc)

After convolution I am getting  the wavelet power spectrum. But I am stuck at COI i.e. the cone of influence.

I found out zero padding is needed and after that I can use conofinf. But this 'conofinf' needs string of an wavelet which is default.

So I am pointing out my questions:
1. How to zero pad my data for wavelet analysis (if there is any particular method)?
2. How can I specify the COI in my wavelet power spectra?

Any help will be great!!

Answer (score 2):

Zero padding is not obligatory, but it's recommended. Usually, you pad your signal to the next power of two greater than the length of you signal. You can do it either manually, something like:

`newSignal = [zeros(1,floor(n)), oldSignal, zeros(1,ceil(n))];`

where `n` is length of required zero padding divided by two:

`n = ( 2^nextpow2(length(oldSignal)) - length(oldSignal) ) / 2;`

It shouldn't necessarily be on both sides; it can be padded from the right. It also shouldn't be zero padding; it can be symmetrical, repetitions etc., whatever is better for reducing edge effects. You can read more about signal padding, e.g. in [this paper](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0493(1993)121%3C2858%3AAITWAI%3E2.0.CO%3B2), in section 2.

You should be careful with zero (and any kind of) padding, it also introduces artifacts, for instance zero padding reduces power at the edges.

Zero padding has nothing to do with COI. You should be able to calculate it even without zero padding.

Using MATLAB's `conofinf` is very handy, but since you can't do it what you can try is to calculate COI by yourself using the formula in MATLAB's help:

`|t-u| <= sB`

where u is translation parameter of the wavelet, s is the scale parameter and [-B,+B] is the effective support of the wavelet.

Basically, it means that at the edges of you wavelet transform (at times t1 and tend) COI is equal to half of the wavelet length at each scale. You calculate it for each scale and plot point by point.

Last note: no matter which type of padding you choose, you shouldn't forget to cut it in the resulting wavelet transform (after calculating COI).

Hope it helps.